# Mysql JSON column any index ( [*] ) not working

Tags: mysql, json

I have a JSON column named prices_and_tags in which there are values in JSON array:

```
[{'price' => 100, 'tag' => 'Watch'}, {'price' => 200, 'tag' => 'Book'}]
```

If I want to search prices_tags where tag = 'Watch' in any array index, it's not working.

Query is like this:

```
select * from products where prices_and_tags->"$[*].tag" = 'Watch'
```

this gives 0 results.

But this query works for first or second array index, like this:

```
select * from products where prices_and_tags->"$[0].tag" = 'Watch'
```

I referred to this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-path-syntax.html for query syntax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
select * from products where prices_and_tags->"$.tag[*]" = 'Watch'
```

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html